# Passing functions with require

Tags: javascript, require, module.exports

I want to pass functions with require. Here's the code:

multerModule.js

```
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');

// Create storage engine
const initStorage = (conn, bucketName) => new GridFsStorage({
  db: conn,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: bucketName
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});


const initUpload = (storage) => multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
    const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    if (ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.gif' && ext !== '.jpeg') {
      return callback(new Error('Only images are allowed'))
    }
    callback(null, true)
  }
});

module.exports = { initStorage, initUpload };
```

offers.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');

const collectionName = 'offers';
const bucketName = 'offers';

const { initStorage, initUpload } = require('../../modules/multerModule');

const conn = mongoose.connection;
Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
  // Init stream
  gfs = Grid(conn.db);
  gfs.collection(collectionName);
});

const storage = initStorage(conn, bucketName);

const upload = initUpload(storage);
```

And I get TypeError: storage is not a function

I think that I could to that by writing something like(correct me if I'm wrong):

```
module.exports = {
    function1: function(params) {//do something},
    function2: function(nextparams){//do something}
}
```

, but isn't a way to do that in this first way through these defined before module arrow functions ?

Comment: Right now, your `storage` variable holds something of the type that `new GridFsStorage` resolves to. `new x` usually resolves to an *instance* of something, not a *plain function*. Instances very often have methods, but an instance is pretty much never a function in itself

Comment: Oups, I'm sorry for the topic, I just changed the name storage to initStorage  and upload to initUpload and forgot to save. However this method works perfectly, but let it be here, maybe someone who will have a problem with this can find help with this solution. I get many help here too.